# >How to set background for all times?

Tags: android

I want to set background that save this change for all times.
I can set background.But after restarting program this change doesn't save.
 
I want to set background by javacode for everytime.
I need it for setting of my app.

Comment: Add some more description or explain what you want!

Comment: if you want save use shared Preference

Comment: Save to sharedpreferences then use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the background color you can use SharedPreferences. Here is some tutorial about how it works : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

I hope it helped